# Query strings in jquery pagination ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

The problem is the following (Sorry for my english if it's not correct):

I am using a library called "Jquery_pagination" and the pagination works at 100% without any inconvenience. The problem is that when the user clicks on some part of the pagination, for example page number 2, it works correctly but when he clicks the return button of his browser he returns to the initial page and not to the previous page of the page pagination ... Is there any way to make this work? I was thinking of adding a GET parameter in the URL as

```
            http://localhost/mycontroller/jobs-in-brazil?page=1
```

but I do not know how to do it either. I need it to be purely ajax.

I'm using Codeigniter.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You can take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) first and learn [How to Ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example. It will be easier for us to help you if you provide us this code.

Answer (score 0):

Just use the codeigniter default pagination plugin and try this :

```
<script>
$(function(){
   $("#pagination-div-id a").click(function(){
   $.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: $(this).attr("href"),
   data:"q=<?php echo $searchString; ?>",
   success: function(res){
      $("#containerid").html(res);
   }
   });
   return false;
   });
});
</script>
```

Hope this helps !!!